# Adding API output to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, api

I'm trying to make a food bank finder for food banks in California. The API data can be found [here](https://controllerdata.lacity.org/dataset/Food-Resources-in-California/v2mg-qsxf). So far, the data opens up on a separate tab (due to the target being "_blank") But I would want the data to output on the screen once the user presses the button, and only specific parts of the data (the name and address of the food bank). How would I show the output on the website and only specific parts of the data? Thank you for your time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://controllerdata.lacity.org/resource/v2mg-qsxf.json"></script>
<title>Sample Page</title>
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-64 spacing" id="location">
    <div class="w3-col l6 w3-padding-large, spacing">
      <h1 class="w3-center">Find a location</h1><br>
        <h5>Enter you zip code below</h5>
    </div >

    <div class = "relative">
    <form action="https://controllerdata.lacity.org/resource/v2mg-qsxf.json" target="_blank" method="get" >
    <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="number" id="zip_code" name="zip_code"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
   
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

form.onsubmit = () => {
var zip_code = document.getElementById('zip_code').value;
fetch('https://controllerdata.lacity.org/resource/v2mg-qsxf.json?zip_code=' + zip_code)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        output.innerHTML = res[0].name + ' - ' + res[0].street_address;
    });
return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
  <input type="number" id="zip_code" name="zip_code"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>

<div id="output"></div>
```

It shows desired results (name and address) on the same page (try, for example, zip code 94501).

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution seems fully HTML based. I think that you can best do this in JavaScript however, doing an asynchronous request for the data using the API like this:

```
fetch('https://controllerdata.lacity.org/resource/v2mg-qsxf.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // do something with data here
    console.log(data)
  });
```

You can add a button that triggers a JS function to search in the retrieved data.